# Can you change the order in which IIS6 virtual directories appear?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have a shared development server with many virtual directories running off one of the websites. Is it possible to reorder how these virtual directories are displayed in IIS?

I tried looking at the metadata, using the Metabase Explorer, but there doesn't seem to be anything that drives the display order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS Manager shows the sites in the order they were entered...

The only way I have found is to click on the websites folder then reorder by description / host header in the main window to get them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "displayed" in IIS, do you mean the Internet Services Management snap-in? If so, it's my belief that it always presents virtual directories in an alphabetically sorted order, regardless of the order they are stored in the metabase.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the ISM snap-in. It definitely is not displaying them in alphabetical order. It seems to be entirely random.

Oddly enough, the Metabase explorer did show them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article: http://windowsitpro.com/web/article/articleid/25937/iis-informant-using-metaedit-22-to-resequence-virtual-directories.html the vdirs are displayed in creation date order (but it can depend on IIS and Win version).

The article suggests a way to reorder them by exporting the metabase to a text file, edit file to reorder the vdirs and reimport.